# "colorWithCalibratedRed:green:blue:alpha:" will not work 

Tags: cocoa, appkit

I would like to create a colour using NSColor but none of the static constructors seem to work for me. The screenshot describes the issue I am experiencing.

[image]

I am referencing:

```
#import <AppKit/NSBitmapImageRep.h>
```

And have imported the framework "AppKit". What else do I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first of all, you haven't imported `NSColor.h`. `NSBitMapImageRep.h` does not import `NSColor.h`, nor do any of its sub-includes. However, one included header *does* declare `NSColor` as a class, which is why you don't get a warning about that.

But you generally don't import specific headers from a framework -- you should import the framework header instead. So doing

```
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>
```

should do the trick.

Of course, if this is a Cocoa app (and generally, AppKit is used as a part of Cocoa, not a standalone framework) you should be linking Cocoa.framework and doing

```
#import <Cococa/Cocoa.h>
```